# One Click Check in to social networking sites

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, foursquare

I want to integrate some of the social networking site like FourSquare, Facebook, Twitter. Now what I want to perform is, in a single click it should update the check in status to all the social networking sites.

The problem that I am facing for now is if I get location for FourSquare I am not able to update check in status for FB & Twitter.

Any help or suggestions for this will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

When using [checkins/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) to check a user in, you can set the `broadcast` param appropriately to broadcast a check-in to this user's connected Facebook and Twitter accounts.